# Why do my python dictionaries keep overwriting

Tags: python, dictionary

What I am trying to do is create a dictionary within a dictionary. It is supposed to be a movie lover's club in which you can add movies to a member's account, but when I try to add it, it gets overwritten. 
Below is my code:

```
import sys

movies = {}


def option_one():
    print('Club Members')
    print('=' * 12)
    for name in movies:
        print(name)
    application()


def option_two():
    name = input('Please enter the user\'s name: ')
    for movie in movies[name]:
        title = movies[name][movie]
        watch = movies[name][movie]['Watched']
        rate = movies[name][movie]['Rating']
        print('Movie', 'Rating', 'Watched', sep=' ' * 5)
        print('=' * 30)

        print(movie, movies[name][movie]['Rating'], movies[name][movie]['Watched'], sep=' ' * 8)

    application()


def option_three():
    name = input('Please enter the member\'s name: ')

    if name in movies:
        movie = input('Please enter the name of the movie: ')
        movies[name][movie]['Watched'] = movies[name][movie]['Watched'] + 1
        for movie in movies[name]:
            if movie not in movies[name][movie]:
                print('Movie not found. ')
            else:
                print('Times watched incremented. ')
    else:
        print('Sorry, member not found. ')
    application()


def option_four():
    name = input('Please enter the member\'s name: ')

    # if the name exists in movies add the movie
    if name in movies:
        # enter information and update dictionary
        movie_title = input('Enter movie name: ')
        times_watched = int(input('Enter times watched: '))
        rating = input('Enter rating: ')
        add_movie = {name: {movie_title: {'Watched': times_watched,
                                          'Rating': rating}}}
        movies.update(add_movie)
        print('Movie added')

    # if name not in movies print member not found call option 4 again
    else:
        print('Member not found')
        option_four()
    application()


def option_five():
    name = input('Enter new member name: ')
    nameDict = {name: ''}

    # update the movies dictionary with name dictionary as key
    movies.update(nameDict)
    print('Member added')
    application()


def application():
    print('=' * 33)
    print('Movie Lover\'s club')
    print('=' * 33)
    print('1. Display all club_members.')
    print('2. Display all movie information for a member.')
    print('3. Increment the times a specific movie was watched by a member.')
    print('4. Add a movie for a member.')
    print('5. Add a new member.')
    print('6. Quit')
    print('=' * 33)

    # get name input for selection
    name_selection = (input('Please enter a selection: '))

    # if statement directing name choice to corresponding method
    if name_selection == '1':
        option_one()

    if name_selection == '2':
        option_two()

    if name_selection == '3':
        option_three()

    if name_selection == '4':
        option_four()

    if name_selection == '5':
        option_five()

    if name_selection == 'Q':
        print('=' * 33)
        print('Thank you for using Movie Lover\'s Club')
        print('=' * 33)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        input('Pick a number between 1 and 5 or Q to exit program. Press enter to continue.')


application()
```

The code above is working as expected but it will not add movie titles only overwrite them. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you include a sample of what `movies` looks like?

Comment: Why do you have add_title, add_watch, and add_movie at the beginning of the last couple of statements when you're not using them?

Comment: because you overright everytime the name: `movies[name] = {movie_title: {'Watched': '', 'Rating': ''}}`

Comment: The whole thing is built on user input except the 'movies' dict which would be like: movies = {name: {movie_title: 'watched', rating}}. So basically name, movie_title, watched and rating would be defined by user input. The layout in my head is dict = {nameDict: {titleDict: value, value}}

Comment: @MohamedMoselhy I am trying to build the dictionaries so that I can add the user input to those values that I created.

Comment: @princedakkar refer to the answer that either I or MohamedMoselhy posted, it should solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit2**: With your updated code, here's the solution to your problem. You were actually really close, the only issue was that you were using `.update` on the `movies` dictionary, rather than the `movies[name]` dictionary, so you would replace `movies[name]` with your new movie dict each time. The solution here is to update `movies[name]` instead. Also, I made a change to your `option_five` function so that when you add a new member, they have an empty dictionary by default rather than an empty string, so it can be updated:

```
def option_four():
    name = input('Please enter the member\'s name: ')

    # if the name exists in movies add the movie
    if name in movies:
        # enter information and update dictionary
        movie_title = input('Enter movie name: ')
        times_watched = int(input('Enter times watched: '))
        rating = input('Enter rating: ')

        # notice how I got rid of {name: ...} and instead only used the movie
        new_movie = {movie_title: {'Watched': times_watched, 'Rating': rating}}
        # now update the user's movie dict rather than the entire movies dict
        movies[name].update(new_movie)

    # if name not in movies print member not found call option 4 again
    else:
        print('Member not found')
        option_four()
    application()

def option_five():
    name = input('Enter new member name: ')
    nameDict = {name: {}} # notice that I replaced '' with {}

    # update the movies dictionary with name dictionary as key
    movies.update(nameDict)
    print('Member added')
    application()
```

Now you can add movies for a user at will without overwriting

Comment: movies = {} movies = {name:{movieTitle: 'watched, rating}} is what I am trying to create. Is this the proper why to design a dictionary, maybe that's what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @princedakkar I just updated my post to do what I think you are trying to do

Comment: @princedakkar this way, if you already have a dictionary for the user, you can update it with a new dictionary stored under the key of the `movie_title`. If there isn't already a dictionary there, you can add a new one with `movie_title` as a key. So you will end up having the structure `movies = { 'Bob': { 'Batman': { 'Watched': 5, 'Rating': 10 }, 'Inception': { 'Watched': 3, 'Rating': 10 } } }`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, and I get that structure completely, it's when I try to use variables from user input when things get messy.

Comment: @princedakkar does it not work with the updated code?

Comment: maybe I should post the entire program code here so you can see what I am doing?

Comment: Yes it will work as long as I tell it 'name' and 'movie' it's just when I begin introducing the variables

Comment: @princedakkar yeah that would be great, so I can test it out as well. If you update the code in your post I'll try running it and see if I can reproduce your issues

Comment: @princedakkar no problem, just let me know once you've added the code

Comment: I have posted the code let me know if you have any questions about my weird thoughts on how this is supposed to work in my mind lol

Comment: @princedakkar I just updated my post with the solution. You were really close, you were just updating the overall dictionary and therefore replacing the `movies[name]` dictionary each time, rather than updating the `movies[name]` dictionary itself

Comment: I see what you did and makes perfect sense thank you but now I get an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update' on line movies[name].update(new_movie)

Comment: @princedakkar make sure to make the change I mentioned to the function `option_five` too. That's causing your error

Comment: I changed it so that every new member added has an empty dict by default, rather than an empty string, so you can call `.update` on the dict to prevent that exact error

Comment: It works, so cool thank you for your help. Something so simple can wreak such havoc lol

Comment: @princedakkar no problem and haha yup my issues that take the longest to debug are always some obscure thing

Answer (score 0):

The reason it gets overwritten is because you overwrite a member's list every time you would like to add a new movie. Specifically, when you execute:

```
add_title = movies[name] = {movie_title: {'Watched': '', 'Rating': ''}}
```

`movie[name]` now only contains `{movie_title: {'Watched': '', 'Rating': ''}}`

Here is a new version of your code:

```
def option_four():
    name = input('Please enter the member\'s name: ')

    # enter information 
    movie_title = input('Enter movie name: ')
    times_watched = int(input('Enter times watched: '))
    rating = input('Enter rating: ')

    if name not in movies:
        movies[name] = {}

    #create the movie title value dictionary make 'movie_title input the name of dict
    movies[name][movie_title] = {'Watched': '', 'Rating': ''}

    #add watched and rating values to the movie_title dict
    movies[name][movie_title]['Watched'] = times_watched
    movies[name][movie_title]['Rating'] = rating
```

Comment: @awarrier99 I posted it before I saw your answer

Comment: I thought as long as a key is different it will not be overwritten and each movie should be a different title so should it not add the title to the movie key? Am I missing something here?

Comment: That would work too, except you're reassigning a new dictionary to `movies[name]` each time

Comment: @princedakkar I updated my answer, that should suit your purpose